# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdxdydz=0$ $\quad$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

let

$f(x,y,z)=xe^{(-(x^2+y^2+z^2)+x+y+z)} (    (x^2+y^2+z^2)(3x^2-2x(x^3+y^3+z^3)+x^3+y^3+z^3) +5x(x^3+y^3+z^3) )$

I was investigating whether $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdxdydz=0$ $\quad$ but I was unable to show that and I was unable to show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdxdydz\ne 0$